# C++ calculator program is skipping an if statement even though it compiles fine

Tags: c++

I am relatively new to c++ programming and was building a simple calculator as a project. The program asks the user to input a number, then asks them to input an operator, if the operator is +, -, * or / it asks the user to enter another number then solves the problem. If the user enters something besides the previous operators like ^ then it instead asks the user to enter a power to raise the number by. The program compiles fine but when you input ^ it seems to skip the if statement and asks you to enter another number, then it asks you to enter a power and completely crashes the program. Any help would be appreciated! Myles.

The program:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <tgmath.h>

long double power(int x)  
{
long double p;
std::cout << "please enter a power:";
std::cin >> p;
return pow(x, p);
}

long double op(long double x, char n, long double y)
{
if (n == '+')
return x + y;
if (n == '-')
return x - y;
if (n == '*')
return x * y;
if (n == '/')
return x / y;
if (n == '^')
power(x);
else
return 0;
}


int main()
{
using namespace std;
int numb;
char calc;
int numb_2;
cout << "please enter a number:";
cin >> numb;
cout << "enter an operator:";
cin >> calc;
if (calc == '+' || '-' || '*' || '/')
{
cout << "please enter another number:";
cin >> numb_2;
long double final = op(numb, calc, numb_2);
cout << "your number is: " << final;
}
else 
{
long double sq = power (numb);
std::cout << "your answer is: " << sq;
}
}
```

Comment: *even though it compiles fine*  -- Just because a program compiles fine doesn't mean it is logically correct.  A successful compilation only means that there are no syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't doing what you think it does:  `if (calc == '+' || '-' || '*' || '/')`.  You need to do every comparison explicitly:

```
if (calc == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/')
```

or use a `switch` statement.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare calc with +,-,... Individually and do "or" operation on those results. Also add return keyword before the call to power() in op function.

Answer (score 1):

What the expression `calc == '+' || '-' || '*' || '/'` does is maybe not that intuitive. What it does is compare `calc` to `+` and if that's true the expression yields true, otherwise it evaluates `'-'` and if that evaluates to true (which it does) the expression yields true (then there's a couple of "otherwise" again that will never happen).

The `||` operator works in the way that it evaluates the left-hand sub-expression and if that's true the evaluation stops there and the expression is true, otherwise the right-hand subexpression is evaluated and if that's true the expression becomes true, otherwise it's false.

The `==` operator has higher precedence than the `||` operator (because you normally want that).

What you would probably want to do is to have a comparison between the `||`s.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you've problem in your following if statement

```
if (calc == '+' || '-' || '*' || '/')
```

change it to following statement

```
if (calc == '+' || calc == '-' || calc == '*' || calc == '/')
```

this works in my machine fine.